# Best way to check if the user enable or disable any permission?

Tags: android

I have 2 buttons first button has this id `id="@+id/button_A"` and second button has this id `id="@+id/button_B"`

`button_A` I named it `text="areNotificationsEnabled ( On )"`

`button_B` I named it `text="canDrawOverlays ( Off )"`

I want when the user block or unblock app notification, So update `button_A` to On or Off. Same thing with button_B.

I can solve the problem using `onResume` but there is exceptions like the user can block notification from status bar without leave the app or using split screen to turn on or off [canDrawOverlays](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#canDrawOverlays(android.content.Context))

I solved the problem using [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) and make check every 250 milliseconds but I think it's not good way to do that, What about [onWindowFocusChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#onWindowFocusChanged(boolean)) or there is better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know this is not possible in the traditional view system.

However, it is possible with Jetpack Compose, Accompanist & some experimental api - see [Accompanists Github](https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/) for details and the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/compose-in-existing-ui?hl=fr) for how to implement it in traditional view systems

```
//inside a composable 
val cameraPermissionState = rememberPermissionState(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
Text("camera permission enabled = ${cameraPermissionState.hasPermission}")
```

---

While this solution will work "just fine" it might come with a pretty steep learning curve. I suggest you go this route only if you intend to start using compose anyhow.